# How to change the value of this.random_variable from html in component.ts Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Instead of having all the code from onblur in html I have to make a function in component.ts. But I have no ideea how to pass for example the this.type from html to component.ts such that when i change the value in component.ts it should change it's value in html as well.

```
<input id="date" type="text" #date
min="{{minDate|date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" max="{{maxDate|date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" 
placeholder="Today" 
onfocus="
    this.type='date'
    document.getElementById('date').addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
        if (e.which == 13) {
            this.blur();
        }
    }); 
    " 
onblur="
    selected_date=this.value.split('-');
    min_date=this.min.split('-');
    max_date=this.max.split('-');
    if(  ( parseInt(selected_date[0], 10) > parseInt(min_date[0], 10) && parseInt(selected_date[0], 10) < parseInt(max_date[0], 10)) ||
         ( parseInt(selected_date[0], 10) == parseInt(max_date[0], 10) &&  parseInt(selected_date[1], 10) < parseInt(max_date[1], 10) ) ||
         ( parseInt(selected_date[0], 10) == parseInt(max_date[0], 10) &&  parseInt(selected_date[1], 10) == parseInt(max_date[1], 10) &&  parseInt(selected_date[2], 10) <= parseInt(max_date[2], 10)) ||
         ( parseInt(selected_date[0], 10) == parseInt(min_date[0], 10) &&  parseInt(selected_date[1], 10) > parseInt(min_date[1], 10) ) ||
         ( parseInt(selected_date[0], 10) == parseInt(min_date[0], 10) &&  parseInt(selected_date[1], 10) == parseInt(min_date[1], 10) &&  parseInt(selected_date[2], 10) >= parseInt(min_date[2], 10))
    ){
        this.type='text';
        this.value = selected_date[2].toString() + ' ' + selected_date[1].toString() + ' ' + selected_date[0].toString();
    }
    else{
        if(selected_date == ''){
            this.type='text';
        }
        else{
            this.type='text';
            error='Please enter a valid date';
            this.value=error.toString();
        }
    }"
>
```

Comment: Andrei, you use,e.g. `(focus)="yourFunction()"` and define the function in .ts `yourfunction(){...}`. See that the [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding) are equals in javascript removing the "on" and between parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.

One of the simplest is ngModel. Basically links a variable to a field.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="varName" (blur)="functionName(varName)">
```

In component you will have a funciton like this:

```
ngOnIt(){
varName = '';
}

functionName(string varName) {
//**do stuff**
//the varName inside brackets is not required as 
//"this.varName" will already have the value
    }
```

Comment: replace in your answer the `onblur` by `(blur)`

Comment: Changed now, I never actually used the onblur before so assumed OP was correct. Thanks!